# Qt5, Webgl and QGLWidget

Tags: webgl, qt5, qglwidget

I have a huge application rendering a 3d scene in a c++ QGLWidget. Is it possible using Qt5 & webgl to add a scripting layer to the application in order to interactively "paint" on the QGLWidget? How?

Answer (score 0):

In QGLWidget, you would use Native openGL API to draw, and input APIs to take input. In WebGL code, you would use WebGL (along with Canvas wrappers) to draw. What is the meaning of "interactive paint" operation here ?